# Controller is not registered -angular js unit testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Hi i am new to unit testing in angular. I am trying to add a simple test, but i keep getting an error saying that my angular controller is not registered. Below is my test case. I am not sure where i am going wrong?

```
'use strict'; 

/**
 * 
 */
describe('Controller',function() {   
    beforeEach(module('Module')); 
    var $controller;  
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;   
    }));

    it("Should initialize AllValues to an empty array",function() {
        var $scope = {

        };

        var testController= $controller(
            'TestController', {
                $scope : $scope
        });

        expect(testController.AllValues).toEqual(new Array());
    })
});
```

below is my file structure in  karma.conf.js

```
files: [
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'App/**/*Test.js',
    'App/**/*Module.js',
    //'App/**/**.js',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't include 'TestController' refrence in 'specrunner.html'

Comment: Hi Nahid.. i am using karma to run my tests.. do i still require a specrunner.html

Comment: No then it's ok. You just missed to inject your controller that's the main problem. This will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42920038/6467840

Comment: I have the controller associated with my module, not sure why its still not recognizing it

Comment: Did you reference the ` <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular-mocks.js"></script>` in your file which inject the controller service and so on in testing. You can also find mock file in your angularjs script folder.

Comment: i updated my karma.conf.js file , are you referring to adding the angular mocks library in karma.conf.js file?

Comment: All I can say that you are missing controller name or reference.  Add controller file TestController in your karma.conf.js  file and make sure you use the proper controller name in test file to inject .

Comment: Thanks Nahid its working. I had to give the complete path of my controller in files , i think i was not giving the wild characters correctly